# How to search global variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, search, global-variables

Is there any tool or regexp that might help to get list of all global variables in JavaScript project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can loop through the window object for querying all globally defined data (variables and functions, including predefined ones):

```
for (var key in window) {
    console.log(key + "=" + window[key]);
}
```

For analysing the source code, use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).

Comment: Worth mentioning that *for..in* will only return enumerable properties, also better strictly to use the global object as not all user agents have a window object.

Answer (score 2):

I quite like the Firebug extension on Firefox.

Here is the DOM tab enumerating all the properties in the Global (ie. window) object and colouring them by type, these are essentially your global variables.

[image: Firebug DOM tab]

Answer (score 1):

You can use browser extension that helps with such things like:

-Firebug extension in Firefox

-Developer Tools window in Chrome

-Dragonfly in Opera

Answer (score 0):

I used this regex to show me all the javascript variables in my project code.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]* = .*;
```

Then I visually scanned the matches to make sure that all my variables were not global. (i.e. there were 'vars' next to them, so long as they were not parameters passed to a function).

For me, I used Sublime Text 2's awesome multi-file search by allowing regex and disabling the context around the match. I also told the search to only search in the folder containing my own javascript files, so it would not show variables from other frameworks or languages. That made it so that every variable appeared one after the other, and it was a ton easier to see any global variable leaks.

Hope this helps and wasn't too confusing. I'm a regex newb but this worked for me. I already found 3 global leaks in my own project in about 5 minutes.